# In Flash Builder is there a way to duplicate/branch a project?

Tags: flash, eclipse, flash-builder

I have a file that I've been working on, and i want to take what I have and modify it heavily, but I want to keep the original; if there was a 'duplicate' project command I would do that, but I don't see one, and wondered if there might be a way to keep it all in the same project for tidiness purposes.  I'd just copy paste the directory myself but just want to make sure I'm not missing some functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice for that is using a SCM (SVN, GiT, ...). You can easily revert a project/file to a previous state.

If you don't use one, Eclipse keeps a local history for each of your files. (Team->Show Local History)

And if you really want 2 projects, I don't think there is a command for that.
Copy paste the directory and changes the name of the project (.project file)